# Custom Object not allowing link back to person account record

Tags: custom

Have 2 basic custom objects for inventory items that have person accounts affiliated with peieces of that inventory..  One of the custom objects allows me click right thru to the person account record.  The second does not and gives me a "You can't view this page is it because you don't have permission or because the page isn't supported on mobile devices."
any help on this matter.  Think I just might be missing a setting in the setup of the Custom Object

Comment: have you checked FLS?

Answer (score 0):

This seems a security setting issue and you should check following checklist:

1. do your profile have access of this Object?
2. If you are using permission set, then have you assigned this object to permission set assigned to you.

If this does not help you, then please paste the screen shot of your problem.

Thanks